# What is wrong with these pine trees?

Tags: trees, diagnosis, pest-control, diseases, pines

There are a line of pine trees in my development, and two of them seem to have a disease. I was hoping someone could identify what is wrong with them. They seem to both have the same problem (part of the branches are dead and there is something wrong with the trunks).

First tree: [image: Tree 1]

Second tree: [image: Tree 2]

Here is an album of both of the trees (shows the branches):
https://imgur.com/a/iki3F

Comment: What type of pine?  I see a little bit of foliage and could be Grand Fir or Doug Fir?  With age part of this could be normal.  Please send a picture of the entire tree and another of the line of trees and a close up of the foliage.  Or two.  Please take a magnifying glass and look at the foliage and stems and bark...let me know what you can see.  Cool season grasses tell me you are north America???  Do you know about Cooperative Extension Services?  There is usually one big University in your state that hosts this service.  Cheap or free, experts that are local to your environment...

Comment: Had any drought in the last 3-4 years? Sometimes pines take that long to die from one.

Answer (score 2):

They're goners I reckon - both pictures show white fungal sheets on the trunk, but the first photo also shows amber coloured ooze, which is certainly canker, and possibly bacterial canker. I recommend you call an arborist to determine whether they're still safe, if they can be saved, and if not safe, remove them, and also check the state of the other trees in the line, just in case the  original cause is at the root, which might mean the others may develop a problem.